# Need Core Data help to insert objects

Tags: iphone, core-data

First of all I want to show how I made this in SQL:

[image]

Both the location and environment table will never contain more than those four rows. Each log can only be associated with 4 rows.

What I don't understand is how do I even start writing code that will take whatever the user has chosen, based on state switches etc in my UI and persist this?

Because when the user are done I want to store a "log-record", and the log-record may have location and environment rows associated with it. And what happen when the user let say, choose all the location rows, four times a row....does it add the location to the location "entity" every time? Would I end up with a lot of duplicated data? I would appreciate any help that can show me how to do this. Thank you!

Comment: You have a join table? Do you mean you have made a join table by hand or you have used core data's relationships to specify many-to-many?

Comment: @deanWonbourne I have used Core Data so that is managed for me, but that was an example if I should have done it in SQL without Core Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need three entities. You'll have Location and Environment entities that have whichever attributes they need, and a Log entity that has relationship with both Environment and Location. I think you're asking if instances of Location and Environment that happen to be the same will be duplicated in the core data store, or if multiple Log instances will relate to the same Location and Environment instances. Is that right? Answer: It's up to you. Say you want to save a Location instance that has a particular set of attributes. You could first search for one that has that exact set of attributes and associate it with your Log instance, or you could just create a new Location instance and not worry about the duplication. If you're storing zillions of these Log entries, the first plan might save a lot of space. If you're not saving them all that often, and particularly if the user can go back and change the data associated with a Log instance, you might want to use separate instances even if they happen to be the same.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So what you say is that whatever location/enviroment thats stored together with a log entry, will be duplicated over and over again, even though the user only has 4 options to choose from?

Comment: I'm saying that Core Data doesn't automagically condense similar objects into one. It's up to you to handle that. If you only have n possible Location objects, it may be a good idea to search for the one you want and associate it with your Log instance. If you create a new Location instance every time the user makes a log entry, you'll get separate copies.